# Ruby on Rails Precompiling assets failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've been following the reInteractive ruby on rails (15 min blog), and in the end of the post (second part), I got an error using heroku to upload my files:

```
! Precompiling assests failed

!Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:peaceful-sea-8032.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master <pre-receive hook declined>
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:peaceful-sea-8032.git'
```

ps: The app runs fine on localhost, I saw some similar question  but I did not have success trying their solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precompile your assets locally. In your shell cd to your application folder and enter:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

This will precompile your assets locally
Then you have to

```
git add .
git commit -am 'precompiled assets'
git push heroku
```

(eddited last line)

Comment: Hi Ksu, thanks for the help.
I precompiled with this command: bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production and then  I try to commit but this sentence appears: fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense, do you know what is it? I made a quick search and didn't found the solution

Comment: Did you have a gap (whitespace) between '-' and 'a'.  ? Please try again with copy-pasting the commands.

Comment: Well, I am not sure what I did wrong in the first time, but I retype and it works now, I'm having some other issues but that's all for this question, thank you so much for your time. See you later! =)

Comment: I fixed it, it's working 100% now, thanks... again xD