# Having trouble pushing commits to heroku

Tags: ruby, git, heroku

So I'm trying to do my first deploy to Heroku from the command line, and when I run "git push heroku master" I get the following error:

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fierce-crag-    
8770.git
```

There are similar errors discussed elsewhere, and one of the proposed solutions is to first do a git pull and then try to push.

If I run

```
"git pull heroku master"
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master
Unexpected end of command stream
```

Another solution was to run this code line by line:

```
$ rake assets:precompile
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Add precompiled assets for Heroku"
$ git push heroku master
```

I got as far as "rake assets:precompile", but then got a "rake aborted" error message.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `git remote -v` show you?

Comment: heroku  https://git.heroku.com/fierce-crag-8770.git (fetch)
    heroku  https://git.heroku.com/fierce-crag-8770.git (push)
    origin  git@github.com:fowlertm/simplecasts_saas.git (fetch)
    origin  git@github.com:fowlertm/simplecasts_saas.git (push)

Comment: So the remotes are pointing to the right location.  What does `git fetch heroku` produce?

Comment: Running that didn't do anything.

Comment: Okay.  Try `git fetch` (which should default to your `origin` remote), followed by `git status`.  Does it tell you if you're behind, ahead, or if your branches have diverged?

Comment: Told me that I had changes to the README file I needed to commit. I committed them and tried the "git push heroku master" again, still got the same error.

Comment: You left out the critical lines of the error message, which should come before `! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)`.

Comment: Okay, here are a some more lines: remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to fierce-crag-8770.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/fierce-crag-8770.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fierce-crag-8770.git'

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the key line is the one *before*  `[remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)`.

This is not about divergent history, but about a hook which prevents the push to complete because of that line.
And it is:

```
 [remote] ! Precompiling assets failed
```

But this is only the conclusion of a more complete stack trace, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28336132/6309): only that stack trace would explain the error.